Does the parent Pom.xml generate bootstrap and application yaml files in src/main/resources of child projects in spring boot?
I have a spring boot project in which the parent Pom.xml is present in a separate microservice. It has this following block:
<!-- Turn on filtering by default for application properties -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/application*.yaml</include>
                    <include>**/application*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/application*.yaml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

Does this mean if I create a new maven project that references the parent Pom configuration, will these yaml files get created in the new maven project automatically or do I have to create it manually in src/main/resources?
I have created a new maven project and converted it to faceted form and build path. I could not see src/main/resources, so I added it in the build path. Now I am trying to build the new maven project and I expected to see the yaml files genrated automatically in src/main/resources but these yaml files are not generated. Is it correct to create them manually?
